# How to convert a query with a function from MongoDB to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mongodb

I have a query from mongoDB that converts the "created_at" string dates into a real workable date that works perfectly in the mongo shell.

```
db.sample_collection.find().forEach(function (tweet){ db.sample_collection.update({_id: tweet._id}, {$set: {created_at: new Date(tweet.created_at)}});});
```

I seem to have a problem in transforming it into PHP query because of the function. Here's what I have so far:

```
$collection->find()->forEach(function (tweet){ $collection->update(["_id"=> tweet->"_id"], ['$set'=> ["created_at"=> new Date(tweet->"created_at")]]);});
```

I dont understand why it returns this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\maps\main.php on line 26
```

EDIT

```
Array ( [_id] => MongoId Object ( [$id] => 5a68a55f36914747e4895f56 ) [created_at] => Wed Jan 24 15:25:20 +0000 2018 [id_str] => 956186162061770752 [text] => Just WOW! #elnido #palawan #matinloc #family #tour #2018 #instagram #instagrammer @ Matinloc Island ....and so on
```

Comment: Based on your previous question. Try `$cursor = $collection->find();

foreach ($cursor as $doc) {
    $collection->update(["_id"=> $doc->_id], ['$set' => ["created_at" => DateTime::createFromFormat('M j H:i:s P Y',$doc->created_at)]])
}`

Comment: @Veeram Yea I am really stuck with this problem. I've tried that solution before by transforming the function into a loop in PHP. But same as yours, it  returns an error like this `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in`. And it bugs me so much because foreach is already a shortened for-loop which you dont need to assign variables for iteration. Btw the looping is all correct cos it prints the `Notice` with the same number of documents I have

Comment: Also tried `$doc["created_at"]`. Still no luck.

Comment: `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\gmaps_thesis\main.php on line 48` it outputs this Notice. But my map still shows nonetheless. It just doesnt do what its supposed to do.

Comment: @Veeram It's printed like this `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\gmaps_thesis\main.php on line 48`.

Comment: Can you output the cursor document to see what it has before updating ? `foreach($cursor as $doc) {
    print_r($doc);
}`

Comment: @Veeram There, i've updated the question for you to see the result. So it actually contains the JSON object that we're trying to update.

Comment: Why does it reads as `Array` it should instead be a `Object` ? Can I see a document from your collection that you are trying to update ?

Comment: @Veeram To tell you honestly, I have no idea. Just started with mongoDB a while ago. Maybe it has to do with the structure of the tweet? Im just streaming twitter JSON from Twitter streaming API and storing it raw/untouched inside mongoDB.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163810/discussion-between-veeram-and-karl).